# android things:Use Speech to text in Raspberry Pi 3 using android things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, speech-to-text, android-things

im using below code for speech to text for Raspberry Pi3

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");


                try {

                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                   a.printStackTrace();
                }
```

But code not works 
it gives exception as

> device does not support Speech to text

Is there any way to support speech to text for Raspberry Pi using android things or any package or apk need to install on Raspberry Pi to support Speech to text.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

The offline speech recognizer does not work on Android Things, but there are cloud-based ways where you send audio to a server and get back the user transcription, such as the [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/).

If you have a specific set of intents that you are listening to, you may want to check out the [Dialogflow API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/detect-intent-audio), which uses Google Cloud Speech behind the scenes with natural language processing. There is also the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/), which would let you embed the full Google Assistant.

Comment: here means I have to create a audio file and send it to the Speech api ?what is the daily free limit to use that api

Comment: You'd have to check the specifics of each API. They may support streaming audio, but if you create a recording in memory you should be able to send the whole payload at one time.

Comment: Is it ok to use Opensource library pocketphonics for speech to text in android things instead of using Google Cloud Speech API.

Comment: Sure, it's fine if it works. I'm not familiar with that library to say for sure.