# how to save the name of the detected objects from tensorflow api object detection in a text file?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, raspberry-pi3, object-detection

I am doing object detection using tensorflow api by following the link"
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

I want to get voice output of the names of the detected classes with their accuracy..I think first I should create a text file which contains the name of the detected objects...How can I create the text file??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text-to-speech (TTS) module that works under Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612298/text-to-speech-tts-module-that-works-under-python-3)

Comment: This question really equates to "how do I do text to speech in Python?" To which there are many solutions, the tag `text-to-speech` has a lot of related questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166326/android-thingsuse-speech-to-text-in-raspberry-pi-3-using-android-things

Comment: Were you able to get the voice output ?? I am also trying to get the text file first with the names of detected classes. But no clear instructions anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the detected object's name as a string by using "display_str_list[0]" inside of draw_bounding_box_on_image function (at line 118) which is in visualization.py class.

For example, you can show detected object's name on the console;

```
print(display_str_list[0])
```

You should put it inside of draw_bounding_box_on_image function (at line 118).